# Why does JPA execute a delete statement for the wrong table?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

I am programming a simple forum using Java EE. The forum has thread and post entities. All the basic CRUD operations for the posts and threads are working.

Only when I try to delete a thread, JPA is making a wrong SQL statement and I don't understand why. I am using the Oracle 11g database.

Wrong statement from JPA:

```
delete from THREAD_POST where Thread_id=?
```

How it should be:

```
delete from FORUM.THREAD where Thread.id=?
```

It looks like JPA is trying to use a join table between thread and post.
Hope fully someone can point me to the right direction to fix this error.

The code I execute to delete a thread:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

em.remove(em.find(Thread.class, id));
```

My Thread entity:

```
package ee.forum.ejb.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "FORUM", name = "THREAD")
public class Thread implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "THREAD_ID_GENERATOR",
            sequenceName = "SEQ_THREAD",
            schema = "FORUM",
            allocationSize = 1,
            initialValue = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "THREAD_ID_GENERATOR"
    )
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Board board;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private User author;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Post> posts;

    public Thread() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public boolean addPost(Post post) {
        if (posts == null) {
            posts = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        post.setThread(this);
        return this.posts.add(post);
    }
}
```

And my Post entity:

```
package ee.forum.ejb.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "FORUM", name = "POST")
public class Post implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "POST_ID_GENERATOR",
            sequenceName = "SEQ_POST",
            schema = "FORUM",
            allocationSize = 1,
            initialValue = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "POST_ID_GENERATOR"
    )
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 1000)
    private String text;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Thread thread;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private User author;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;

    public Post() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Thread getThread() {
        return thread;
    }

    public void setThread(Thread thread) {
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your actual code, `THREAD_POST`  is never referenced.

Comment: Your OneToMany bidirectional association mapping is wrong. You defined a OneToMany unidirectional association, and a separate ManyToOne unidirectional association. Read the hibernate docuemntation. It's really as siple as that: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet . I added a "mappedBy" parameter on the OneToMany side in the Thread entity and its's working now. Perhaps you can write an answer so I can mark it as best answer.

Comment: You can just delete your question. It's being asked once every two days, and adding more answers doesn't seem to help people to avoid that mistake.